# Smooth image replace ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to make a ASP.Net MVC 4 page that has a big image in the center and buttons to the next or previous image.
I want a smooth transitions (No refresh) of images.
Should the image be partial view replaced with ajax or a link to an action?
like so:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetCurrentSlideImage") " />
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "smooth image transition" and what you have tried to do so. That also has little to do with MVC, as you do it with JavaScript.

Comment: As I am starting to learn web programming from MVC - this is what I know. Also I believe that action is a term related to MVC not Javascript.

Comment: You just use MVC's `@Url.Action()` to print the image's URL. Effects in the browser are accomplished using JavaScript.

Comment: Yes that is one way but I also know I can replace the image using partial view and I wanted to know if that is correct way to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jquery plugins for that.

For example, find and get `jqFancyTransition` plugin and import it to your view.

For static use, you can do like the following:

```
<div id='slideshowHolder'>
    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/SlideShow/1.jpg")' alt='1' />
    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/SlideShow/2.jpg")' alt='2' />
    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/SlideShow/3.jpg")' alt='3' />                
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $('#slideshowHolder').jqFancyTransitions({ 
            width: 315, height: 236, 
            effect: 'random top', 
            direction: 'random', navigation: true});
    });
</script>
```

And for dynamic use, send urls and alts of image through your model to the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Image>

// ...

<div id='slideshowHolder'>
    @foreach(var img in Model)
    {
        <img src='@Url.Content(img.Url)' alt='@img.Alt' />
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Do I need to have all the image beforehand? what if I only want to fetch the image upon some button click? do I still use <img src='@Url.Content()' ?> ?

Comment: @kroiz - Yeah. Fetching images you want, is completely separated from showing them. To achieve your aim, you should use some `@Ajax.BeginForm()` to submit some info to controller when that button clicked and get relative images.

Comment: Doesn't Form imply refresh of the whole page?

Comment: @kroiz - No. As I said `Ajax`... you should use `@Ajax.BeginForm()`. Try to perform it in your partial view.In 90% You'll get another issue! Then ask another question about that problem...

Comment: I don't have a partial view, And I did not think I need one until you mentioned it...

Comment: @kroiz - Using partial view will ease your work very much. Otherwise, you should rely heavily on javascript and jquery to submit data ajaxly, retrieve them from controller and render them in your view...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35501/discussion-between-kroiz-and-aminsaghi)